# Can't get the app icons to stop displaying "waiting"

Tags: ios, ios-appstore

I tried to update multiple apps at once. On the available updates screen, I pressed all. Now the icons are black and if I press them nothing happens. They have been downloading for hours, so I tried to cancel the download by going to Settings, however, that wasn't successful. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I've had this happen before too. Usually restarting the iPhone/iPad fixes the issue. There's a great set of instructions on how to fix this located here..

http://www.iphonefaq.org/archives/971489

> 1. Reboot your iPhone normally. See this link for instructions on how to restart your iPhone.
> 2. If the apps are still stuck on the home screen, try logging out of the App Store temporarily. Navigate to Settings -> Store -> Apple ID
>      -> Sign Out. Now open the App Store and Navigate to the Featured section. Scroll to the bottom of the page and touch the Sign In -> Use
>      Existing Apple ID. Log in and the stuck apps should reset.
> 3. Still have strange icons on the screen or frozen downloading apps? Connect your iPhone to the computer and open iTunes. Navigate to the
>      app store. Install the apps you are having a problem with on the
>      computer then sync your iPhone.

Comment: Matches my experience mostly, but before restarting you can also pause the downloads by tapping them, and start one at a time after the restart. Sometimes that has avoided needing to sign in and out, a big time saver when helping some slow-typing users.